# struts2 jquery indicator dialog

Tags: jquery, struts2, indicator

I'm building a web application using struts2 and the jquery plugin. I'm trying to use the "indicator" functionality included in the jquery plugin. Indeed I would like to fire a popup saying "loading..." when the user performs some actions (button clicks, list selection...).

So I have this master page MasterPage.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>  
<head>
<s:url id="customTheme" value="/template/themes" ></s:url>
<sj:head defaultIndicator="indictor" jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="warrtheme" customBasepath="%{customTheme}" />
</head>
<body>

<sj:dialog id="indicator"
           title="Loading"
           autoOpen="false"
           modal="true"
           resizable="false">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img src="<s:url value="/images/indicator.gif" />" /></td>
        <td>Loading...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</sj:dialog>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have this regular page User.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<div class="content">
    <s:url var="openViewUser" namespace="/administration" action="administration_utilisateur_open" />
    <sj:a href="%{openViewUser}" id="divUserLink" targets="divUser" indicator="indicator">

    <div id="divUser"></div>
</div>
```

When I click the link in the above code, the popup doesn't show up.
Any clue guys ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this right ? <img src="<s:url value="/images/indicator.gif"/>">. i think it shoud be <img src="images/images/indicator.gif" />

Comment: good remark. Actually both are working in my case. But this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: yeah thats not problem solver i know i just wanted to know that this things works too or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to subscribe the **open** topics or you have to trap the **onclick** event .Suppose you want to show dialog on click

```
   function openDialog() 
    {
        $("#indicator").dialog('open');
    }
```

and once the ajax is loaded successfully ,close the dialog box using this

```
$("#indicator").dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post the complete code that works for me...

On the MasterPage.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>  
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<s:url id="customTheme" value="/template/themes" ></s:url>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="warrtheme" customBasepath="%{customTheme}" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript">
$.subscribe('onBeforeLoading', function(event,data) {
    $("#indicator").dialog('open');   
}); 

$.subscribe('onCompleteLoading', function(event,data) {  
    $("#indicator").dialog('close');   
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<sj:dialog id="indicator"
       title="Warning"
       autoOpen="false"
       modal="true"
       resizable="false">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img src="<s:url value="/images/indicator.gif" />" /></td>
        <td>Loading, please wait...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</sj:dialog>

</body>
</html>
```

And on the User.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<div class="content">
    <s:url var="openViewUser" namespace="/administration" action="administration_utilisateur_open" />
    <sj:a href="%{openViewUser}" id="divUserLink" targets="divUser" onBeforeTopics="onBeforeLoading" onCompleteTopics="onCompleteLoading" >Click me</sj:a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="divUser"></div>
</div>
```